# CUDA ./deviceQuery fails sometimes

Tags: nvidia, gpu

My setup: Ubuntu 16.04 CUDA 8.0, driver 375.39

`./deviceQury` fails only sometimes. Usually it works fine. Now it failed after waking up from suspend mode. After reboot, it works fine.

output:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 30
-> unknown error
Result = FAIL
```

Comment: I have the same issue. [here's a suggestion that may work for you](https://askubuntu.com/a/750939/21645), but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is with version 375.39.

I saw something on [this thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/993603/linux/rock-and-hard-place-375-26-fails-to-suspend-but-required-for-cuda-8-0/) on the CUDA Zone forum which worked for me.

Just change drivers by going to Dash -> Additional Drivers and then select the 378.13 or 381.09 driver, and then restart. It has worked for me.